# Xcode clang error when adding SDWebImage framework

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, clang, sdwebimage, xcode7-beta6

I am trying to compile an app that use SDWebImage, when I add the framework to xCode I keep getting the following error.

I have attempted to add the framework by clone the git repo

```
ld: framework not found SDWebImage
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you added the files to the Build?

Comment: @Ares I believe so, see above screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linking in Xcode requires a bit of work. We can tell what to do or suggest a better way. As I consider "dropping framework" solution a very bad habit, I'd strongly suggest a better way:

**Use dependency manager!**

This will help you to see whenever your dependencies get new updates. You'll also know which version are you using. This is a good practice.

You can eg use [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/). Go to your Terminal, type:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then go to your project folder (place, where you have `xcodeproj`) and type:

```
$ pod init
```

This creates a file named `Podfile`. Open it and paste:

```
platform :ios, '8.0' // or whatever you need
use_frameworks!

pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7'
```

So when you have it ready, open Terminal and type:

```
$ pod install
```

From now you should work on `xcworkspace` instead od `xcodeproj`. Your dependency should work correctly.

BTW: There are many other solutions. You can simply use [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). You can also use [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage). However most popular and as for me atm most convenient way is [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/), so I wrote steps for this way.

Answer (score 0):

You've added SDWebImage as a linked framework.

What you should be doing is adding it as an Embedded framework, and make sure that your build phase copies the framework into your app bundle.