# How to import objective c header file in swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhEcT.png)

I am trying to use SDWebImage in a Swift project. I dragged and dropped the SDWebImage library folder into my Swift project and created a bridging header by name listingApp-Bridging-Header.h

Then I imported the header file into my Swift file; like so imported

```
    import UIImageView+WebCache.h  

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell : TableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! TableViewCell


    let strTitle : NSString = arrDict[indexPath.row].valueForKey("clip_name") as! NSString

      cell.clipName.text = strTitle as String


    cell.videoImage sd_setImageWithURL=NSURL URLWithString,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",K_Server_imageurl,[record valueForKey:@"clip_image_path"]];



        return cell

}
```

It's giving me an error saying `add ; before +` How would I import the file above into my Swift project correctly?

Comment: Do you have use_frameworks! uncommented in your podfile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Objective C code from Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Comment: i am not using pod file

Comment: can you show the error

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32303778/how-to-install-sdwebimage

Comment: @virat check my answer

Comment: see the image i have added

Comment: now it is giving me error in viewController.swift file that : at this line import UIImageView+WebCache.h like this it is giving me error saying add ; before + sign that consecutive statements must be separated by ;

Comment: ok i have edited my code have a look so how should use sdimage now to set my image view to show images

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to quote the header file name when importing it in the bridging header. Like this:

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h";
```

This is exactly the same syntax as importing header files in objc.

Comment: imported header file like #import UIImageView+WebCatche.h in the bridging header also

Comment: Then you should be able to use the code in swift without importing anything in swift file.

Comment: it is giving error in my bringing header file as "UIImageView+WebCatche.h" file not found

Comment: You need to check the project header search path. And adding the 'umbrella' header would be better than adding headers individually.

Comment: now it is giving me error in viewController.swift file that : at this line import UIImageView+WebCache.h like this it is giving me error saying add ; before + sign that consecutive statements must be separated by ;

Comment: sorry, i forget to append semi-colon after the import statement. See my updated answer.

Comment: You don't need to import anything in your swift file because you have imported them in the bridging header.

Comment: ok i have edited my code have a look so how should use sdimage now to set my image view to show images @Fijia

Comment: thanks your comment :  
You don't need to import anything in your swift file because you have imported them in the bridging header. – worked for me

Answer (score 8):

It's not enough, you must add this bridge header filename also in your Build Settings - Swift Compiler Code Generation like in this picture:

[image]

Don't forget also this (required by `SDWebImage`):

[image]

About the next step:

```
imageDownloader.downloadImageWithURL(
                        NSURL(string: urlString!),
                        options: SDWebImageDownloaderOptions.UseNSURLCache,
                        progress: nil,
                        completed: { (image, data, error, bool) -> Void in
                            if image != nil {
                                self.bannerImageView.image = image

                            }
                    })
```

Comment: it is giving error in my bringing header file as "UIImageView+WebCatche.h" file not found

Comment: done with all your suggested steps but now its giving me error in bridging header file as : 
 "UIImageView+WebCatche.h" file not found

Comment: Have you drag and drop the full proj?

Comment: now it is giving me error in viewController.swift file that :   at this line  import UIImageView+WebCache.h  
like this it is giving me error saying add ; before + sign  that consecutive statements must be separated by ;

Comment: now it is giving me error in viewController.swift file that : at this line import UIImageView+WebCache.h like this it is giving me error saying add ; before + sign that consecutive statements must be separated by ;

Comment: You must also make a clean of the project, try to remove derivedData, then re-build all

Comment: not working deleting derived data also please check the image i have added

Comment: ok i have edited my code have a look so how should use sdimage now to set my image view to show images

Comment: No please, stop it. You cannot change your question on the fly whenever you want, please open another question and flag this as answered (choose the answer you want): people have just answer to the main question title, if you change your question content this thread become completely 
incomprehensible